# Pass arguments from a file to multiple spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

Is it possible to have one master file that stores a list of arguments than can be referenced from a `spark-submit` command?

Example of the properties file, configurations.txt (does not have to be .txt):

`school_library = "central"
school_canteen = "Nothernwall"`

**Expected requirement:**

Calling it one spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars sample.jar \
/home/user/helloworld.py  configurations.school_library
```

Calling it in another spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars sample.jar \
/home/user/helloworld.py  configurations.school_canteen
```

Calling both in another spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars sample.jar \
/home/user/helloworld.py  configurations.school_library configurations.school_canteen
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can do that by the conf `--files`

For example, You are submitting a spark job with a config file: `/data/config.conf`:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster 
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  --files /data/config.conf \
  /path/to/examples.jar
```

And this file will be uploaded & place in the working directory on the driver. So you have to access by its name.

Ex:

```
new FileInputStream("config.conf")
```

Comment: And how do I pick up specific variables from the config.conf on the `spark-submit`?

Comment: I use json format for my config file. Then, i can read it easily

Comment: Json is fine, but how do I pass a specific element in that json?

Comment: What do u mean? Since your file is a JSON file. U can read the whole json file & read, get everything in that json.

Comment: If you look at my question, it says that the file(json) will have multiple variables, I want to pick up a particular variable form a list of variables that the files stores and pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Spark-submit parameter "--properties-file" can be used.
Property names have to be started with "spark." prefix, for ex:

```
spark.mykey=myvalue
```

Values in this case extracted from configuration (SparkConf)